# Get Python Executable to Write to Google Big Query

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-bigquery, executable

I created a Python script that works fine when I run it through Spyder.  Basically, I'm querying some files and merging a couple data frames into one final data frame.  All of this works perfectly fine.  Then, I created an executable from this .py file, and I'm trying to run the .exe but it's giving me a problem.  Here's the issue.

```
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'google-cloud-bigquery' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

So, basically, when I try to push the data frame into Google Big Query, this causes an error.  It seems like 'google-cloud-bigquery' is not setup in the virtual environment.  I followed the instructions from the link below to try to ensure everything is setup correctly.

https://cloud.google.com/python/setup

After going through all those steps, I'm still getting the error described above.

This is the line of code that causes the error:

```
df3.to_gbq(destination_table, project_id=proj_ID, if_exists='append')
```

Any thoughts on how to get this working?

Comment: Run: `pip install -U google-cloud-bigquery`

Comment: Thanks John.  I tried what you suggested, re-ran the process, and got exactly the same results as before.  I can completely understand if one system doesn't have permissions to communicate with another system, but I think it's weird that it's all Google-based and it doesn't work.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: Your comment `I'm trying to run the .exe `. This is something that I have not tried, so I don't know.

Comment: I tried to do the same thing using a Google Cloud Function.  I had similar errors.  How would someone use GCP to run a Python script?  I have seen a lot of documentation on this, but so far, I haven't been able to make anything work.

Comment: Very interesting comment. I do a lot of development (C#, Python and Node.js) for GCP and I seldom have problems. This indicates that your development environment is not setup correctly and / or when you upload your code you are not including everything (requirement.txt for Cloud Functions in Python, etc.). Without more details, I could only guess.  For your Cloud Functions problem, create a new question. There are many of us that can help with that service and this will narrow down the problem and the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded pyinstaller, and my exe worked with google-cloud-bigquery. The bug was fixed with pyinstaller version 4.2.

pip install --upgrade pyinstaller